# How to get tcp/udp socket's recv buff's cap and currently data size in buff?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

`getsockopt()` only get the cap of socket. I can't find get data size in buff anyway?

Comment: The amount of data in the buffer might change the microsecond after you query it, so I'm not sure that knowing that figure actually helps you much.  That said, you could do a `recv()` and pass in the `MSG_PEEK` flag and see how much data is returned.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, use `ioctlsocket(FIONREAD)`

On Posix systems, use `ioctl(FIONREAD)`